# new nexus 7 2013 is not accepting correct resource folder xhdpi

Tags: android

I have old nexus 7 2012 and now i have new one also. but same application behaves differently in both devices. as new nexus is having different resolution so i am not getting why dynamic imageview and dynamic text are behaving different. image size is getting smaller and text size is increased from 11 to 18 in new nexus. i have tried with layout-large-xhdpi and values-large-xhdpi but it is still behaving same. please help and suggest what should i do so same application can run in new nexus also perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

for drawables  `drawable-large-xhdpi`

for layouts `layout-large`

for values `values-large`

Comment: "Large" was deprecated two years ago. Use "sw600dp" instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
     // Figure out what kind of display we have
          int screenLayout = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout;

          if ((screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL)
             LogMessage("Main onCreate", "Info", "Screen size is Small");
          else if ((screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL)
             LogMessage("Main onCreate", "Info", "Screen size is Normal");
          else if ((screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)
             LogMessage("Main onCreate", "Info", "Screen size is Large");

          if ((screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_LONG_YES) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_LONG_YES)
             LogMessage("Main onCreate", "Info", "Screen size is Long");

          // Get the metrics
          DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
          getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
          int heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
          int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
          int densityDpi = metrics.densityDpi;
          float density = metrics.density;
          float scaledDensity = metrics.scaledDensity;
          float xdpi = metrics.xdpi;
          float ydpi = metrics.ydpi;

          LogMessage("Main onCreate", "Info", "Screen W x H pixels: " + widthPixels  + " x " + heightPixels);
          LogMessage("Main onCreate", "Info", "Screen X x Y dpi: " + xdpi + " x " + ydpi);
          LogMessage("Main onCreate", "Info", "density = " + density + "  scaledDensity = " + scaledDensity +
             "  densityDpi = " + densityDpi);

***please have these lines in yours manifest***

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
 />
```